# JSON Deserialization not working

Tags: apex, json

I need to show the result of a Web Service Response that comes in JSON format in a Visual Force page.

The issue is that when I test, the class did not recieve the JSON results, instead recieves null strings.

[image: This is the test result:]

This is the Apex Code I'm using:

```
 string msj = '{'+
                 '"NroDocumento":"20520869655",'+
                 '"Consulta":"Empresa"'+
                 '}';

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('endpointwashere');
    req.setBody(msj);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setTimeout(12000);

    HttpResponse res = Http.send(req);
    String responseBody = res.getBody();

    Equifax.Empresa empresita = (Equifax.Empresa)JSON.deserialize(responseBody,Equifax.Empresa.class);
    System.debug(empresita);
    System.debug(responseBody);
```

The JSON raw result:

```
{
"Empresa": [
    {
        "RazonSocial": "INSTITUTO DE EDUCACION SUPERIOR TECNOLOGICO PRIVADO TOULOUSE LAUTREC SAC IT",
        "NombreComercial": "INSTITUTO DE EDUCACION SUPERIOR TECNOLOGICO PRIVADO TOULOUSE LAUTREC SAC IT",
        "RUC": 20520869655,
        "TipoContribuyente": "SOCIEDAD ANONIMA CERRADA",
        "EstadoContribuyente": "ACTIVO",
        "CondicionContribuyente": "HABIDO",
        "Dependencia": "I.PRICO NACIONAL",
        "CodigoCIIU": 80904,
        "DescripcionCIIU": "EDUCACION DE ADULTOS Y OTROS",
        "InicioActividades": "12/01/2009",
        "ActividadComercioExterior": "SIN ACTIVIDAD",
        "NumeroTrabajadores": 1349,
        "Direccion": "AV. PRIMAVERA 607 OFICINA 508"
    }
]}
```

The class I'm using to deserialize:

```
public class Equifax {

public class Empresa{
    public String RazonSocial; 
    public String NombreComercial;  
    public String TipoContribuyente; 
    public String EstadoContribuyente;
    public String CondicionContribuyente; 
    public String Dependencia; 
    public String CodigoCIIU; 
    public String DescripcionCIIU; 
    public String InicioActividades; 
    public String ActividadComercioExterior; 
    public String NumeroTrabajadores; 
    public String Direccion;

}}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that's causing you grief here is that your JSON response specifies a *list* of `Empresa` objects, but your code assumes that this information is contained as a single JSON Object.

A list of size 1 is still a list.

The Apex class you use to deserialize needs to match the structure of the data you're receiving.

So, instead of

```
public class Equifax{
    public class Empresa{
        // fields defined here
    }
}
```

You need to make your outer class contain a List of your inner class

```
public class Equifax{
    // When inside of the Equifax class, you don't need to use the fully-qualified
    //   name for the inner class.
    // Also, as with your Empresa class, the variable name needs to match the key name in your JSON.
    //
    public List<Empresa> empresa;

    public class Empresa{
        // fields defined here
    }
}
```

That change alone should be most of what you need.

The only other change would be to deserialize as an instance of your `Equifax` class (instead of `Equifax.Empresa`).

The results you're looking for would then be accessible via `empresita.empresa[0]`

Comment: Thanks Derek, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reason it is not deserializing correctly is your JSON has a list but your class does not. There is a nice tool called JSON2Apex to generate correct classes. [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)

For example generated class looks like this:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class Equifax {

    public class Empresa {
    public String RazonSocial;
    public String NombreComercial;
    public Long RUC;
    public String TipoContribuyente;
    public String EstadoContribuyente;
    public String CondicionContribuyente;
    public String Dependencia;
    public Integer CodigoCIIU;
    public String DescripcionCIIU;
    public String InicioActividades;
    public String ActividadComercioExterior;
    public Integer NumeroTrabajadores;
    public String Direccion;
}

public List<Empresa> Empresa;


public static Equifax parse(String json) {
    return (Equifax) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Equifax.class);
}
```

}

And you can deserialize your JSON like this:

```
Equifax empresita = Equifax.parse(responseBody);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also working.